# how to assign a test file in resharper?

Tags: nunit, resharper

how to assign a test file in resharper?

whenever I select 'run tests' it says no test file found.

I created a test project, how do I link it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only done minimal work with NUnit and Resharper, but the way I've always done it is just write all of the test code in your test project, and link/include the library you want to test using `using` statements. Make sure to include the `[TestFixture]` and `[Test]` attributes in your test classes, and when you select "Run Unit Tests" in VS on your test project, it should go through each `[TestFixture]` class and run all of the `[Test]` functions.

All that being said, I have found that running nunit tests in Resharper (v3.1 at least) to be less than ideal. It does not recognize some test conditions such as `ExpectedException`, so I always run my tests directly in NUnit itself.

Comment: missing the textfixture, doh!